# Refreshing ArcGIS Feature Server Layer Data

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to refresh a layer's data every 30 seconds from an ArcGIS Feature Server.  I toggled on this option which I thought would accomplish this; however, it doesn't update the data - it just redraws the layer. How do I force QGIS to re-request the data from the server?

[image: Refresh Option]

Comment: How many features are in the service? If it's more than a score or two, it could very well be deemed a denial of service attack to hit the server that often.

Comment: @Vince - Currently there are just 12 features.